# Fileupload fileUploadListener only invoked every second button press

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I'm trying to upload files with the fileupload component in primefaces 5.2, but I found the function bind by fileUploadListener doesn't be invoked everytime. It be invoked when I press the upload button first times, but it not invoke in second time. It be invoked when I press the upload button third times, but it not invoke in fourth time. Below is my code and setting.

**Web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>auto</param-value>
</context-param><filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

**XHtml**

```
<composite:implementation>
        <p:fieldset legend="#{cc.attrs.tittle}" id="transfile" styleClass="fieldset" style="width:60%">
        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{transferFRorzwBean.translate}"
                dragDropSupport="false" mode="advanced" sizeLimit="100000"
                allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(txt|csv)$/" immediate="true"
                label="Open" uploadLabel="Translate"/>
        </h:form>
        </p:fieldset>
</composite:implementation>
```

**Java Code**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TransferFRorzwBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private UploadedFile file;

public void translate(FileUploadEvent event) {
    this.file = event.getFile();
    String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(file.getFileName());
    uploadFileName = filename;
    InputStream input = file.getInputstream();
    String path = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getRealPath("/Protected/upload");
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(path, filename));

    try {
        IOUtils.copy(input, output);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
    }
}
public UploadedFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}
```

IDE : Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1
Server : Tomcat 8.0
Jar : commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar, commons-io-2.4.jar, primefaces-5.2.jar
I also try add below on web.xml, bt not work...

```
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Anyone has ideas for this problem?

Comment: Does your browser's developer console give any output? Just for testing purpose, how does it behave if you remove the `immediate="true"` attribute?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I check the browser's developer console(use IE F12), don't have any useful output. I also test remove the immediate="true", but the behavior was same like I not remove it.

Comment: No one has suggestion? I will try to check java file upload problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding code in java as follows:

```
event.getComponent().setTransient(false);
```